# Customize query according to the condition mongodb + node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't know whether I have too much expectation from mongodb, but I have a question here.

Is it possible to customize the query according to a boolean parameter? Firstly, I have looked https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/.
But didn't find an example where the condition is up to a another parameter.

Here let me clarify by an example;
Let assume I have a `flag` parameter. I want to execute two similar queries based on whether its value is `true` or `false`.

document is like;

```
{ 
    "name" : "alex", 
    "age" : NumberInt(21)
}
{ 
    "name" : "felix", 
    "age" : NumberInt(14)
}
```

To be able to look the condition I can break them into two different query as;

```
if(flag){
  db.collection.find({age: "18"})
}else{
 db.collection.find({age: "21"})
}
```

I am looking for something like this;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$cond: [flag,{$match: {age: "18"}} ,{$match: {age: "21"}}]}
])
```

But this throws an error which is not a surprise.

Is it possible to use `$cond` and execute two different query? Can a parameter pass in the `$cond`?

Comment: Did You find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate query first based on your condition then execute that query one time.

```
var query = {};

if(flag){
  query.age = 18;
}else{
 query.age = 21;
}

db.collection.find(query, function(err, result) {
   if(err) {
      // return error
   }
   console.log(result);
   // return result
})
```